Waiting for deposit to be observed days after activation epoch already passed
I am running a main net eth validator AND a holesky validator on the same machine. The mainnet is doing fine and the Holesky side is synced up on execution and consensus clients, running as expected. The validator on Holesky is the only problem I am having. Current print, "INFO client: Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node" even though my activation epoch past days ago. Here is my beacon chain profile
https://holesky.beaconcha.in/validator/ac99777efa619eebab6c5bb8a30237dc83e5dc7ebb804b38ae386a3696bb898bb8dcecd4b856bb1a844586703de19d99#deposits
I have tried everything I have my ports properly opened on router and my firewall, current commands for holesky execution, beacon, and valiadtor are as follows.
./geth --datadir "/home//holesky/geth-datadir" --http --http.port *** --http.api="engine,eth,web3,net,debug" --ws --ws.port *** --ws.api="engine,eth,web3,net,debug" --http.corsdomain "" --holesky --syncmode=full --authrpc.jwtsecret="/home//holesky/jwt.hex" --port ** --ipcpath "/home//holesky/geth-datadir/holesky_geth.ipc" --authrpc.port ***
./prysm.sh beacon-chain   --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:***   --holesky   --jwt-secret=/home//holesky/jwt.hex   --checkpoint-sync-url=https://holesky.beaconstate.info   --genesis-beacon-api-url=https://holesky.beaconstate.info   --datadir=/home/**/holesky/prysm-datadir   --p2p-udp-port=***   --p2p-tcp-port=***   --monitoring-port=***   --grpc-gateway-port=***   --grpc-gateway-host=***   --grpc-max-msg-size=104857600   --suggested-fee-recipient=*
sudo ./prysm.sh validator   --wallet-dir=/home//holesky/holeskyconsensus/wallets   --datadir=/home//holesky/holeskyconsensus/validator-datadir   --holesky   --suggested-fee-recipient=****   --beacon-rpc-provider=***   --monitoring-port=**
redacted ports etc. but I have triple checked them they are correct and open. Before I was getting this error [2024-07-12 02:31:20]  WARN client: Could not determine if beacon chain started error=could not receive ChainStart from stream: could not setup beacon chain ChainStart streaming client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: http2: frame too large": could not connect: could not connect
before I changed the port numbers and opened them on the router and FW. So I am just out of options Idk what is causing the issue. Is beacon and validator not communicating properly? I checked my JWT token and seems fine? idk though.
